# Unable to install any applications/software

Tags: system-installation

I try using the terminal and the Software Center and everytime, this message pops up:

```
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     desmume : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 6.5.2-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I even tried to do `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal but that does not fix it. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that helps

Comment: Live CD? If Ubuntu is not installed the disk is "read only" and cannot be written to (i.e installing things).

Comment: @CameronBarbeau OP is most definitely not on a live-CD, as he has broken packages, which implies that he has installed other programs and packages. In addition, a LiveCD can be written to if you allocate a small amount of persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Run first this:

`sudo apt-get install -f`
The option -f will fix broken packages in case there are any and also is neccessary sometimes when apt-get is run for the first time.

Then run:
`sudo apt-get update`
and:
`sudo apt-get install desmume`

or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install desmume`
(it is the same but with the &&)

Hope you'll fix the problem!